# Constrain zoom and pan in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to correctly contrain zooming and scaling on my d3-chart using d3's Zoom Behaviour. I've reduced the problem to the following minimal runnable example. I want the user to not be able to zoom in a way that will allow him to see below the 0-line on the y axis.

The sample works when in non-zoomed state, by setting `translateExtent` to the full height of the svg, but that of course breaks as soon as the user zooms in a little. In fact, the further you zoom in, the further you're able to look into the negative area.

What do I need to set the `translateExtent` to?

The reason I'm redrawing the line and axes on each zoom event is that normally I'm using react to render my svg and use d3 just for calculcations - I have however removed the dependency on react to provide a more concise example.

```js
const data = [ 0, 15, 30, 32, 44, 57, 60, 60, 85];

// set up dimensions and margins
const full = { w: 200, h: 200 };
const pct = { w: 0.7, h: 0.7 };
const dims = { w: pct.w * full.w, h: pct.h * full.h };
const margin = { w: (full.w - dims.w)/2, h: (full.h - dims.h)/2 };

// scales
const x = d3.scaleLinear()
  .rangeRound([0, dims.w])
  .domain([0, data.length]);
  
const y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .rangeRound([dims.h, 0])
  .domain(d3.extent(data));

// axes
const axes = {
  x: d3.axisBottom().scale(x).tickSize(-dims.w),
  y: d3.axisLeft().scale(y).tickSize(-dims.h)
}


const g = d3.select('.center');

// actual "charting area"
g
  .attr('transform', `translate(${margin.w}, ${margin.h})`)
  .attr('width', dims.w)
  .attr('height', dims.h)
  
// x-axis
g.append('g')
.attr('transform', `translate(0, ${dims.h})`)
.attr('class', 'axis x')
.call(axes.x)

// y-axis
g.append('g')
.attr('class', 'axis y')
.call(axes.y)


// generator for the line
const line = d3.line()
  .x( (_, i) => x(i) )
  .y( d => y(d) );

// the actual data path
const path = g
  .append('path')
  .attr('class', 'path')
  .attr('d', line(data))
  .attr('stroke', 'black')
  .attr('fill', 'none')

const zoomBehaviour = d3.zoom()
  .scaleExtent([1, 10])
  .translateExtent([[0,0], [Infinity, full.h]])
  .on('zoom', zoom);
  
d3.select('svg.chart').call(zoomBehaviour);
  
function zoom() {
  const t = d3.event.transform;
  
  const scaledX = t.rescaleX(x);
  const scaledY = t.rescaleY(y);
  axes.x.scale(scaledX);
  axes.y.scale(scaledY);
  d3.select('.axis.x').call(axes.x);
  d3.select('.axis.y').call(axes.y);
  
  line
    .x( (_, i) => scaledX(i) )
    .y( d => scaledY(d) );
  
  const scaledPath = path.attr('d', line(data));
}
```

```css
body {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

svg.chart {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.axis line, .axis path {
  stroke: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<body>
<svg class="chart">
  <g class="center"></g>
</svg>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the `zoomed` function in [this example by Mike Bostock](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5e81cc677d186b6845cb00676758a339) which I believe does what you want, the key part is the mutation of `t.x` and/or `t.y` if there's a breach of constraints:

```
function zoomed() {
    var t = d3.event.transform;
    if (t.invertX(0) > x0) t.x = -x0 * t.k;
    else if (t.invertX(width) < x1) t.x = width - x1 * t.k;
    if (t.invertY(0) > y0) t.y = -y0 * t.k;
    else if (t.invertY(height) < y1) t.y = height - y1 * t.k;
    g.attr("transform", t);
}
```

Comment: Sadly, the behaviour this produces is different from what I need. In this example, no part of the image can ever be invisible, so that zooming in is effectively impossible. If you try it in the link you provided, you'll notice that you can never zoom "into" the sample image.

I want my users to be able to do that, they just shouldn't be able to pan "past" the image when zoomed in, i.e. one part of the image must always be visible.

Comment: I didn't mean the above as an exact solution to your use case, more like just showing an extra step not present in your appriach, which is the conditional mutation of `t.x` and `t.y`. Maybe you can tweak the conditions, as Mike's example constrains the entire contents to be always visible, while you want to constrain the contents (I suppose, the bounding box of the line contents) to "surround" your viewport. Just a different condition (content bounding box and viewport box are in the reverse relation compared to Mike's example, if I understand your needs).

Answer (score 5):

I was able to make it work based on the suggestions made by Robert. I had to adjust the conditions a bit to fit my use-case:

```
const dims = /* object holding svg width and height */;
const [xMin, xMax] = this.scales.x.domain().map(d => this.scales.x(d));
const [yMin, yMax] = this.scales.y.domain().map(d => this.scales.y(d));

if (t.invertX(xMin) < 0) {
  t.x = -xMin * t.k;
}
if (t.invertX(xMax) > dims.width) {
  t.x = xMax - dims.width * t.k;
}
if (t.invertY(yMax) < 0) {
  t.y = -yMax * t.k;
}
if (t.invertY(yMin) > dims.height) {
  t.y = yMin - dims.height * t.k;
}
```